# Is there a License Manager?

Tags: license, package-management, autocad

I work at an architectural firm, and our users use a lot of Adobe products or AutoCAD products.

We deploy most software through SCCM, and we have a finite amount of licenses to use.

We need to manually check if there are licenses available before deploying software.  We then need to manually obtain management approval, before adding the computer name to the specific AD group, so SCCM can deploy the software.

This is a bit tedious, in terms of not instantly knowing how many licenses are in use.  Also, Adobe don't offer network licensing, which would make things much easier.

My question is: is there some sort of License Manager application which can handle automated assignment/deployment/management of licenses?

UPDATE: GLPI looks like it duplicates the majority of the functions we already have in SCCM:

- Determine which machines have licensed apps installed.
- Configuration Management
- Driver Management
- Hardware Audits
- Network Audits
- SMS Reports
- SCCM Software Distribution Reports
- Software Update Management
- Upgrade Assessment
- WOL

The only thing missing is automatically determining if there are available licenses before deployment.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple add-ons that may interest you that will solve the issue you are having and further enhance SCCM - as well as, save costs in IT.

Check out the following apps:

AppClarity:  http://www.1e.com/softwareproducts/appclarity/index.aspx

Shopping:  http://www.1e.com/softwareproducts/shopping/index.aspx

AppClarity solves the licensing issue by normalizing SCCM inventory data.  AppClarity can save thousands of dollars alone in licensing costs.

Shopping automates the deployment of the software by including approvals, license verification, etc.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful links.  Does AppClarity save money on licenses due to eliminating duplicates?